# Is it possible to update a Recyclerview item that's not on screenyet?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a Recyclerview adapter class with a few cardviews and those cardviews each have a textview in them that I want to update. I can update the textviews within the cardview by using `notifyItemChanged()`, but it only updates the cardviews' textviews that are in the viewport, but I want to push updates to the cardviews that aren't on the screen yet so that when the user does scroll down, they can see the updated status. So, is there any way to update items in a Recyclerview that aren't visible yet to the user, possibly by holding the value somehow until the off screen data does come on screen?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to change the data of the adapter and then call `notifyItemChanged()` or `notifyItemChanged(int position)`. It should work. You can also explore `RecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)` to get a specific ViewHolder.